Left join later flatten works not like left join, but the same as inner join
With this data:
create or replace table test_json as
select
parse_json('{
            "include": [
                "x",
                "y",
                "z"
            ]
        }') AS val
union all
select
parse_json('{
  "exclude": [
    "a",
    "b"
  ],
  "include": [
    "d",
    "e"
  ]
}');

I have this query:
with source_cte as (
select val, i.value::TEXT as include_symbol
from test_json, lateral flatten(input=>val:include) as i
)
select
include_symbol,
e.value::TEXT as exclude_symbol
from source_cte LEFT JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN(input=>val:exclude) e

Here is the result:
INCLUDE_SYMBOL    EXCLUDE_SYMBOL
     d                  a
     d                  b
     e                  a
     e                  b

It doesn't return rows with include = x, y, z, like it would if I used INNER JOIN LATERAL FLATTEN, but I'm using LEFT JOIN.
Is it some bug in Snowflake?
How to achieve then LEFT JOIN behaviour for such case? I mean to show include_symbol regardless of whether match is found in left join lateral flatten expression (and show nulls in exlude_symbol column in such case).

you should use the same syntax that you are using in the source_cte, but use the outer => true option that is noted in the documentation. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/flatten

this problem can be written much simpler:
with test_json(val) as (
    select parse_json($1) from values
        ('{"include": ["x","y","z"]}'),
        ('{"exclude":["a","b"],"include":["d","e"]}')
)
select 
    val
    ,i.value::TEXT as include_symbol
    ,e.value::TEXT as exclude_symbol
from test_json, 
    table(flatten(input=>val:include)) as i,
    table(flatten(input=>val:exclude)) as e;

and then the fix as Mike points at can be used on the exclude flatten:
with test_json(val) as (
    select parse_json($1) from values
        ('{"include": ["x","y","z"]}'),
        ('{"exclude":["a","b"],"include":["d","e"]}')
)
select 
    val
    ,i.value::TEXT as include_symbol
    ,e.value::TEXT as exclude_symbol
from test_json, 
    table(flatten(input=>val:include)) as i,
    table(flatten(input=>val:exclude, outer=>true)) as e;


and then the val can also be dropped:
with test_json(val) as (
    select parse_json($1) from values
        ('{"include": ["x","y","z"]}'),
        ('{"exclude":["a","b"],"include":["d","e"]}')
)
select 
    i.value::TEXT as include_symbol
    ,e.value::TEXT as exclude_symbol
from test_json, 
    table(flatten(input=>val:include)) as i,
    table(flatten(input=>val:exclude, outer=>true)) as e;


which for your table would read like:
select 
    i.value::TEXT as include_symbol
    ,e.value::TEXT as exclude_symbol
from test_json, 
    table(flatten(input=>val:include)) as i,
    table(flatten(input=>val:exclude, outer=>true)) as e;

